# Javascript paint canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with my code. It is a simple canvas element drawing circles. There are two things I cannot figure out. The first one is how to draw circles continously (not one at a time) while I keep left mouse button pressed. "Onmousehold" doesn't seem to work here. Secondly is it possible to get rid of the first reference error from the console? It appears only once when coordinates of a click are not yet specified. My code here:

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var ctx = outer.getContext("2d");
function getMousePos(e) {
    var cursorX = e.clientX; 
    var cursorY = e.clientY; 
 x = cursorX;
 y = cursorY;
}
function showBox() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
console.log(x,y);
}
outer.addEventListener("click",getMousePos);
outer.addEventListener("click",showBox);
outer.addEventListener("mousedown",showBox);
```

```css
#outer {
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid green;
}
.popup {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="outer" width="600" height="600">
 </canvas>
```

And jsfiddle
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/4ovgzk07/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/4ovgzk07/2/

```
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var ctx = outer.getContext("2d");
function getMousePos(e) {
    var cursorX = e.clientX; 
    var cursorY = e.clientY; 
    x = cursorX;
    y = cursorY;
}
function showBox() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
console.log(x,y);
    outer.addEventListener("mousemove",getMousePos);
outer.addEventListener("mousemove",showBox)
    outer.addEventListener("mouseup",removelisteners);

}
function removelisteners() {

    outer.removeEventListener("mousemove",getMousePos);
outer.removeEventListener("mousemove",showBox)


}
outer.addEventListener("mousedown",getMousePos);
outer.addEventListener("mousedown",showBox);

;
```

Youu need to attach events for `mousemove` when `mousedown` occurs, similarly remove those `events` on `mouseup`